# Time frames for NYSE response?

Tags: stock-markets, markets

I have noticed that when NYSE gives a notice of non-compliance, they usually give about 30 days to the company to submit a response, plan, request extension etc. However, is there a time-frame for NYSE to respond back with an answer, or decision?

I did try looking on the NYSE [rules](https://www.nyse.com/regulation/nyse/rules-and-disciplinary-actions), but could not find anything relevant.